# Execution of arbitrary JavaScript code (not command) in NodeJS child process

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the easiest way to run some code (not command!) in a different process and communicate its result with the main process?

So I have a quite intensive task that needs to be split up into different processes. What's the easiest way to do something like this?

```
// in main process
var otherProcess = createAnotherProcess(function() {
    console.log("this code is ran in another process");
    return "some data";
});
otherProcess.on("done", function(data) {
    console.log(data); // will output "some data"
});
```

Having a single source code file that is able to run code in multiple processes would be amazing! Is this even possible? I've tried reading a bit about "child_processes" in node but find it a little too convoluted.

Any help?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processforkmodulepath-args-options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var stat = spawn("dstat", ["-r", "--noheaders", "--nocolor"]);


var output = function (output_data) {
  //do something with output_data
};

stat.stdout.on("data", output);
```

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/child_processes.html

Comment: So I cannot keep a single source code file? I need to split it into another .js file and call it using `spawn("node myfile.js")`?

Answer (score 2):

To run some command in child process you can use [child_process.spawn](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/child_processes.html#child_process.spawn) method.

If you want to run some heavy JS code you can split it execution to chunks to not block the IO using [process.nextTick](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/process.html#process.nextTick).

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer. The process.spawn and siminal methods are focused on exectuing of command, not JavaScript code as question author asked. May I ask you to add some example with executing of JavaScript code, not commands?

Answer (score 1):

Use [dimas-parallel](https://github.com/shudima/dimas-parallel) (on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dimas-parallel)):

```
var dimas = require('dimas-parallel');

dimas.execute(function() {
  // do some stuff on another process
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `node -e <code>`

Example:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

const child = spawn('node', ['-e', 'console.log("in other process", process.pid)'])

child.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data.toString())
})
```